# Inno Setup refresh desktop

Tags: windows, inno-setup, pascalscript

Is it possible to refresh the desktop using Inno Setup in the `[Code]` section?

Either by using `SendMessage` or somehow use `SHChangeNotify`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call any function in the Windows API by calling it in the appropriate DLL. The Pascal DLL syntax is documented [here](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptdll.htm). The documentation of the [`SHChangeNotify`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762118(VS.85).aspx) function is found at MSDN as usual. This function is found in `Shell32.dll` (no surprise!).

```pascal
[Code]
const
  SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED = $08000000;
  SHCNF_IDLIST = $00000000;

procedure SHChangeNotify(wEventID: integer; uFlags: cardinal; dwItem1, dwItem2: cardinal);
external 'SHChangeNotify@shell32.dll stdcall';

procedure SendChangeNotification;
begin
  SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, 0, 0);
end;
```

Now you can call `SendChangeNotification` anywhere you like, for instance in an [event function](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm).

**Update**

The text above answers your question, how to "refresh the desktop using Inno Setup in the `[Code]` section". But did you know that Inno Setup can refresh the desktop for you, automatically? Simply write

```
ChangesAssociations=yes
```

in the `[Setup]` section. See: [`ChangesAssociations`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_changesassociations)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how does it work? At the moment i'm trying: external 'SHChangeNotify(0x8000000, 0x1000, 0, 0)@Shell32.dll stdcall'; but i get syntax errors.

Comment: @s0mmer: That is not the right syntax. First, the declaration of the function should only state what the signature is and where the function resides (if it is external). The arguments you put in when you call the function! In addition, MSDN states that `SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED` has to be used with `SHCNF_IDLIST` which is zero, not `$1000`.

Comment: This is very useful when we use inno for other tasks e.g. **write small pascal programs**. See [http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Writing_quick_Pascal_programs_with_Inno_Setup](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Writing_quick_Pascal_programs_with_Inno_Setup). Especially since `ChangesAssociations=yes` will **only** be called at the very end of the installation!