# Refresh shell associations in Inno Setup conditionally (only if a function is checked)

Tags: windows, inno-setup, pascalscript

As the title says how can I make that Inno Setup use the:

```
[Setup]
ChangesAssociations=yes
```

Only when a certain function is checked:

```pascal
function installation: Boolean;
begin
  Result := install.Checked; { only if this is checked }
end;

function portable: Boolean;
begin
  Result := porta.Checked;
end;
```

I need that association doesnt get called when I simply extract the portable version of my software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `ChangesAssociations` directive, call [`SHChangeNotify` WinAPI function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shchangenotify) conditionally from [`CurStepChanged(ssPostInstall)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged):

```pascal
[Code]

const
  SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED = $08000000;
  SHCNF_IDLIST = $00000000;

procedure SHChangeNotify(wEventID: Integer; uFlags: Cardinal; dwItem1, dwItem2: Cardinal);
  external 'SHChangeNotify@shell32.dll stdcall';

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    if installation then
    begin
      SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, 0, 0);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This is what `ChangesAssociations=yes` internally does.

---

*Partially based on: [Inno Setup refresh desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5849289/850848).*

Answer (score 2):

Fyi, in the next version you will be able to write:

```pascal
[Setup]
ChangesAssociations=installation

[Code]
function installation: Boolean;
begin
  Result := install.Checked; { only if this is checked }
end;
```

Thanks for the idea :)